# Get the 0-value timestamp date with Carbon

Tags: php, laravel, date, php-carbon

I am attempting to get the 0-value timestamp in an PHP API. I am currently using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) in a Laravel / Dingo API based system.

Is there a simple way to get the 0-value timestamp (presumably something like 01/01/1970) without hardcoding the date?

Comment: The earliest date? Or the 0-value timestamp?

Comment: Apologies for the ambiguity, I was referring to the earliest 'computer' date, so the 0-value timestamp. I'll change my answer to reflect this :)

Comment: timestamps can also be negative, giving you dates earlier than 1st January 1970... the baseline date/time for unix timestamps is 1/1/1970 00:00:00 GMT/UTC (note that it is timezoned)

Comment: Ah, I see. That's quite useful, actually.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could try:

```
echo Carbon::createFromTimestamp(0)->toDateString();
// Displays: 1970-01-01
```

So you do not have to hardcode the date, just use a `0` timestamp.